# Put carriage return in text when drawing graphic

Tags: asp.net

When trying to place text on a bitmap created with the tools in the System.Drawing namespace, how can you put a carriage return in text?

```
var text = "First Floor";
var font = new Font("Verdana", 42);
var textbrush = Brushes.Black;
var point = new PointF(plusC(60), plusC(20));
Graphics.FromImage(bmp).DrawString(text, font, textbrush, point);
```

How can I get First Floor to have a carriage return in it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var text = "First Floor\n";
```

That might not work. From my experience with drawing graphics, there is no way to specify newline or carriage return. Every drawing is dependent on how and where you position them

If I have

```
 DrawString("First sentence", x, y);
```

To achieve new line, I'll have to draw the next object below y

```
 DrawString("Second sentence", x, y + 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried like this:

```
var text = "First Floor\r";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

\r\n did the trick.